# In Matlab, how to solve an equation for a function?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

If I use `solve` to solve an equation for a variable, I get the expected result:

```
syms x
syms a b(s)

f1 = a*x;
f2 = (a - b(x))/2;

solve(f1 == f2, a)
```

yields

```
ans =

-b(x)/(2*x - 1)
```

However, for some reason, if `a` is defined as a function `a(s)` instead of a variable, this doesn't work:

```
syms x
syms a(s) b(s)

f1 = a(s)*x;
f2 = (a(s) - b(x))/2;

solve(f1 == f2, a(s))
```

yields

```
ans = 

  struct with fields:

    s: [0×1 sym]
    x: [0×1 sym]
```

I'm not really sure how to interpret this, but I was expecting the same result as when solving for the variable.

I also get the same result if I try `solve(f1 == f2, a)`.

How can I get Matlab to solve the equation for `a(s)`?